# Can't find the results of a Google Search with BS4 - Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get back the stock price from a Google search but the results of the BS4 are more than 300 lines.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD0Lv.png)

Here is my code:

```
import bs4, requests

exampleFile = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=unip6')
exampleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(exampleFile.text, features="html.parser")
elems = exampleSoup.select('div', {"class": 'IsqQVc NprOob'})
print(len(elems))
for each in elems:
    print(each.getText())
    print(each.attrs)
    print('')
```

I'd like the outcome was only the price: '23,85'

Comment: Google uses JavaScript to create the results, it's not in the HTML source.

Comment: There are many free apis to get a stock price, don't make it harder that it should be because the class names change frequently.

Comment: @PedroLobito actually I'm searching for the stock price market only to exercise the concepts of web scraping. It could be any other... But in this case, you don't recommend Google search because of changes in class names?

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @FelipeDourado I'd definitively go with an api to retrieve any stock price. Yes, I don't recommend scrapping google based on class names as they change frequently. If you want "to exercise the concepts of web scraping", take a look at the source code of [google-search](https://github.com/anthonyhseb/googlesearch/blob/master/googlesearch/googlesearch.py) python package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the page isn't loaded dynamically, so the target details can be found in the soup. It's also possible to avoid the issue of the changing class name (at least for the time being...), by not using a class selector:

```
for s in soup.select("div"):
    if 'Latest Trade' in s.text:
        print(s.text.split('Latest Trade. ')[1].split('BRL')[0])
        break
```

Output:

```
23.85
```

Answer (score 0):

Using yahoo finance, you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now =  datetime.now() # time now
past = int((now - timedelta(days=30)).timestamp()) # 30 days ago
now = int(now.timestamp())

ticker = "UNIP6.SA" # https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UNIP6.SA/
interval = "1d" # "1wk" , "1mo"
df = pd.read_csv(f"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1={past}&period2={now}&interval={interval}&events=history")
print(df.iloc[-1]['Close'])

# 23.85
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/071ec10dbe)

Answer (score 0):

It's much simpler. All you have to do is to use `select_one()` to grab just *one* element since there's no need to use a `for` loop (*use [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors*):

```py
soup.select_one('.wT3VGc').text
# 93,42
```

And don't forget about `user-agent` to fake a real user visit, otherwise, Google will treat your requests as [python-requests](http://and%20don%27t%20forget%20about%20%60user-agent%60%20to%20fake%20a%20real%20user%20visit).

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Search-Scrape-Answer-Box-Stocks-Data-python#bs4_result.py):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=unip6', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

current_stock_price = soup.select_one('.wT3VGc').text
print(current_stock_price)

# 93,42
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the same thing except don't figure out why the output has more than 300 lines by using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "unip6",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

current_stock_price = results['answer_box']['price']
print(current_stock_price)

# 93,42
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi